# Python Django TypeError: argument of type 'Post' is not iterable

Tags: python, django

Ошибка в консоле:

```
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Internal Server Error: /blog/post/create/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 148, in resolve_url
    return reverse(to, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 90, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 622, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'test 10' not found. 'test 10' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\PythonFile\gjango\app\blogengine\blog\views.py", line 30, in post
    return redirect(new_post)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 58, in redirect
    return redirect_class(resolve_url(to, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 154, in resolve_url
    if '/' not in to and '.' not in to:
TypeError: argument of type 'Post' is not iterable
```

Это виновник этого поста

элемент кода из \blog\views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.views.generic import View

from .models import Tag, Post
from .utils import ObjectDetalemixin
from .forms import *


def posts_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', context={'posts': posts})


class PostDetail(ObjectDetalemixin, View):
    model = Post
    template = 'blog/post_detale.html'


class PostCreate(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = PostForm()
        return render(request, 'blog/post_create.html', context={'form':form})

    def post(self, request):
        bound_form = PostForm(request.POST)

        if bound_form.is_valid():
            new_post = bound_form.save()
            #return render(request, 'blog/post_detale.html', context={'post':new_post})
            return redirect(new_post)
        return render(request, 'blog/post_create.html', context={'form':bound_form})
```

И \blog\forms.py который используется в коде выше

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

from .models import *


class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'slug', 'body', 'tags']

        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'slug': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'tags': forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }

    def clean_slug(self):
        new_slug = self.cleaned_data['slug'].lower()
        if new_slug == 'create':
            raise ValidationError('Slug may not be "Create"')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Определите метод get_absolute_url() в модели Post. Если я все правильно помню то в том видео это и происходит (https://www.youtube.com/embed/4O1xdboP0PY?start=1875&autoplay=1):

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post_detail_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

И проверьте если ли у вас в urlpatterns следующая строка:

```
path('post/<str:slug>/', PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail_url')
```

Comment: У меня просто опечатка в название метода.
get_ablolute_url

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ. Бился 2 дня с этой проблемой. Оказывается вместо post/<str:slug>/ у меня было blog/<str:slug>/